# Google Cloud Cloning Disk Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am having an issue while cloning a disk in Google cloud.
I already have a disk (and a VM created), I need another disk/VM similar to it with same setup done.

> Creating disk "vm2" failed. Error: Invalid value for field
> 'resource.sourceDisk':
> 'projects/watchful-scope-130208/zones/us-central1-a/disks/vm1'.
> Regional disk cannot be created from a source zonal disk created from
> an image.

[image]
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Either create an image first from the source disk or a disk in the same **zone** as the source disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating disk in the same zone (create in single zone if your base image is in single zone) as the source disk.
Thank you @John Hanley